# ignore directory in pytest in vscode

Tags: python, pytest

I want to ignore a directory in pytest, but my test discovery fails in vscode:

```
{
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "--ignore backup",
    "."
],

In vscode this is interpreted to:
python /home/dave/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.5.86806/pythonFiles/testing_tools/run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir /home/dave/PythonProjects/mypgram -s
```

I am missing the --ignore backup. Why is it not there or this the wrong place for configuration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution by looking up the pytest syntax:
just use`--ignore=backup` and it will work